# Closed-loop Transfer Function

Tags: power-engineering, closed-loop, block-diagram

[image]

help me answer this. pls show me your solutions, that would be very helpful so i can understand how you did it.

Comment: Please show your efforts to solve this problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework with no own attempt.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

[image]

Can you see what I've done to simplify it i.e. I've helped you with a small first step and split the problem into two halves.

Comment: An answer and encouragement to move forward at the same time +1